# Time complexity of c++ array loop

Tags: c++, complexity-theory

i have the following loop but am unable to calculate the complexity .I need help

```
int A[n][n];
for(int i=0; i<n;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        A[i][j] = x;
    }
}
int sumLine = 0;
for(int k=0;k<n;k++) {
    sumLine += A[k][0];
}
```

i would appreciate

Comment: Complexity is O(N^2)

Comment: Double nested loop, each goes from `0` to `n`.   Complexity -- `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have three loops that you need to analyze.  The first two are a set of nested loops: every time the inner (j) loop runs `n` times, the outer (i) loop runs once.  Because the outer loop eventually runs `n` times, the whole set will run `n*n = n^2` times, so we say that set of loops runs in O(n^2) time.  Once these loops complete, the third (k) loop runs `n` times, which is O(n) time.

When you have two separate operations with different big-O complexities and want to add the complexities together to get their total, you take the larger of the two.  Since O(n^2) is "larger" than O(n), we say that the *entire* program runs in O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity will be O(n^2). Read more about time complexity here - [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm) . It has some good explanation here.